# var() is not equal to sd()^2 in R

Tags: r, variance, standard-deviation

Mathematically, it is evident that var = sd^2 (or var^0.5 = sd), but R seems to answer TRUE for the latter and FALSE for the former.
To my knowledge, both var() and sd() function use n-1 for degree of freedom.
What would be the problem?

```r
data <- c(20, 20, 30, 20, 16, 13, 20)

var(data)^0.5 == sd(data)
var(data) == sd(data)^2
```

Comment: There is no problem. This is about numerical precision. Use the `all.equal` function instead to acknowledge the fact that your machine represents real numbers as floating-point numbers with a specific numerical precision. The documentation  of  `all.equal` also explains `.Machine$double.eps`.

Comment: Thanks! Will find the document you mentioned.

Comment: Try this: `print(x <- 1 + 1e-15, 17); sqrt(x)^2 == x`

Comment: This is [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).

Comment: A good way to visualize the problem: calculate sqrt(13), write the result on a piece of paper, now square your intermediary result and see if you get 13 again. This is what R (has to) do - it's a calculator, not a symbolic equation solver, it doesn't retain knowledge that a specific intermediary result is supposed to be sqrt(13).

Comment: My late Dad, Math Professor, hung his head in frustration when digital calculators first came out & a student divided 1 by 3 and then multiplied the answer by 3 and got 0.999999999 ; actually thought his calculator was broken.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft However many times someone proves it to me, I still hate the idea that mathematicians say 0.999...=1.0   One day I'll find a good counter-argument :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook Then you must love the fact that there are different infinities! :-)

Answer (score 29):

Please, check

```r
0.4^2 == 0.16
0.4 == 0.16^0.5
```

It's not a statistical issue. It's a rounding issue in floating point arithmetics in the language.
The same applies to Python

```py
0.4**2 == 0.16
0.4 == 0.16**0.5
```

None of these floating point numbers is stored in a computer's memory as two- or three-decimal digits, but rather in a binary format.
For instance, `0.16` (8-byte) is stored as 11111111000100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111**011**, while `0.4**2` gives us 11111111000100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111**100**.
You can play with this decimal to binary conversion using the following Python code:

```py
import struct
bin(struct.unpack('!Q',struct.pack('!d',0.16))[0])
bin(struct.unpack('!Q',struct.pack('!d',0.4**2))[0])
```

Comment: Hey Alex - I understand that the above example from mkt is a issue of floating point, but still cannot quite grasp why the two-digit decimal point example of yours(0.4**2) is not identical with 0.16. Can you please further elaborate?

Comment: Hey. I added elaboration to my answer above

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @Hwi-youngLee If this answers your question, consider accepting it (or whichever other answer you see as best) by clicking on the green tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Recommended read for you is

> Goldberg, D. (1991). [What every computer scientist should know about
> floating-point arithmetic.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) *ACM computing surveys (CSUR), 23*(1),
> 5-48.

*TL;DR* you should *never* use `==` (or its equivalent in any other programming language) to compare floating point numbers because they represent numbers only approximately. As in your example, two different computations can lead to floating point representations that are different though close enough given the guarantees given by such representation. What you should do instead is to compare them with some precision, e.g. $|x - y| < \epsilon$, but this is also [not a perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) and there are better ones. Happily, in most cases, they would be already implemented for you in the programming language you are using ([like the mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368153) `all.equal` in R).

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted. Just printing `sd`, one can see that it uses `sqrt(var(x))` to perform the calculation. The devil is thus hidden in floating point arithmetic. And one needs to be aware of the problems hidden there.

Comment: +1 That paper is a classic.

Answer (score 10):

Correct to 14 decimal points, it's a floating point number issue:

```
options(digits = 20)
> var(data)
[1] 27.476190476190474499
sd(data)^2
[1] 27.476190476190470946
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the differences between those quantities. They are likely to be small.

Computers are funky about how they store long decimals.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the difference is indeed very small, but still feeling kind of awkward that it produced FALSE...